# Querying different fields from Multiple Core in Solr

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and I have the following requirement,

I have two cores running on the same tomcat instance.
My requirement would be some thing similar to this:
1. With single Solr query return field1, field2 from Core1 and field3, field4 from Core2. I need all four fields to be returned as a single record.

Please provide me some assistance to achieve this in Solr.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't.

What you describe is sometimes referred to as vertical partitioning. Solr Cores can be searched at once, but they're meant for horizontal partitioning (aka sharding), i.e: the process of partitioning entire documents to different cores.

If you describe the usecase you're trying to achieve perhaps people can help you how to achieve your goal differently.

**update**

from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LargeIndexes
' There is no implementation of a vertical partition across indexes.'

You can accomplish it with low-level methods in Lucene (which underlies Solr) using ParallelReader/Writer, but this is *highly* discouraged bc. there'll be dragons. See http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Vertical-Partitioning-advice-td494623.html for some background.